# Default name changes suddenly when saving file with StringBuilder

Tags: c#, windows-xp, stringbuilder

I built a web application that creates a comma-separated textfile ("tag.csv") using the StringBuilder based on the parameters of an order. That file is then used to feed a metal tag engraving machine with data. The communication Software with that machine only runs under WindowsXP.

The problem I am facing is very strange: After approximately 5 Weeks of working without any problems, Windows suddenly stopped using the filename "tag.csv" during the saving dialog and adds a random string chain to the name: eg. "tag167JH24.csv". That causes that the original tag file is not overwritten anymore and the wrong data set is used for the engravings.

That working station is operated through a low profile worker and the reliability of the process should not depend on him manually changing the filename while saving. I had already changed the default filename from "temp.csv" to "tag.csv" 5 weeks ago after this had happened for the first time, but don't want this to become a monthly routine.

This is the code that builds the file:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(content);

    string text = sb.ToString();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", text.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"tag.csv\"");

    Response.Write(text);
    Response.End();
```

I really have no clue what this behavior is related to. My guess would be WindowsXP...

[image]

Comment: What's the point of using `StringBuilder`  here?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with StringBuilder at all. The interpretation of the "Content-Disposition" header is up to the Browser; id anything change on this side?

Comment: Yes, it most like doesn't have anything to do with the StringBuilder. It might just be related to the browser and I actually can solve this problem by cleaning the Browsers cache. I thought this could be solved programmatically, but it seems to be a feature of the browser that can't be controlled